# What is the meaning of "whin"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, dialects

I am reading the book "1100 words you need to know" and I face with a strange sentence:

“A little drummer boy grinned in me face whin I had admonished him wid the buckle av my belt for riotin’ all over the place.”

Also, I have another problem with some words such as "wid" and "av" in this sentence. I find a little description for wid in [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wid) link that explains wid is dialectal variant of "WITH". It is possible that "whin" and "av" be dialectal variant of "WHEN" and "OF", respectively?

Comment: Your conjecture is correct. Also, "me" is being used as a dialectal variant of "my."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the context is to be spoken/read with an accent. Where the grammatically correct sentence as far as American english would be:

> A little drummer boy grinned in **my** face **when** I had admonished him
>   **with** the buckle **of** my belt for riotin’ all over the place

So I would say yes you are correct in thinking they are dialectal variants of those words.

Comment: Why leave "riotin'" if you're correcting all the other colloquialisms?

Comment: It looks like a representation of an Irish accent. My guess is that it's the Kipling character Private Mulvaney. Odd that it should be quoted out of context with no explanation of the unconventional spellings.